# is there a better way to get information from another class?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working on a program and I wanted to know the best way I can get information from one class to another.

My purpose is to get information from MyTimer to the Program class about how much "ticks" the timer did.

** I don't want from the class MyTimer to be dependent on the Program class (Like by using Program.SetUpdate()). MyTimer class should work with every class without changing his code.

I've already tried using public static method to send the information.

```
class Program
{
    private static int _count;
    private static MyTimer _myTimer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        _count = 0;
        _myTimer = new MyTimer() { Timer_Interval = 100 };

        _myTimer.Start();

        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press q to quit.");
        } while (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString().ToLower() != "q");

        _myTimer.Stop();
    }

    public static void SetUpdate(int count)
    {
        _count = count;

        Print();
    }

    private static void Print()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_count);
    }
}

class MyTimer
{
    private Timer _timer;
    private int _ticks;

    public int Timer_Interval { get; set; }

    public MyTimer()
    {
        _timer = new Timer();
        _timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(_timer_Elapsed);
    }

    private void _timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Program.SetUpdate(_ticks);

        _ticks++;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (Timer_Interval == 0)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("_timer interval can not be 0.");

        _ticks = 0;

        _timer.Interval = Timer_Interval;
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _timer.Stop();
    }
}
```

The output is 1,2,3... until you press q/Q

I've tried to do it as simple as I can only to show you the concept.

So I created a class named Program that call MyTimer class. 
MyTimer class is simply like a timer: stop,start and elapsed. Each interval it makes a "tick".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd normally fix this sort of issue by establishing a "direction". E.g. here it feels natural that it should be "from" `Program` "to" `MyTimer`. In that given direction, it's perfectly fine to make direct method calls, access properties, etc.

When you need information to flow in the other direction, that's when you use [*events*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/). `MyTimer` raises an event and `Program` can have a handler. In this way, `MyTimer` doesn't know which classes are creating it/working with it or even *how many event handlers* have been installed.

Comment: Okey thanks, and my second question is: I want from MyTimer class to be independent and not using the method from Program class. How can I accomplish that? I thought maybe to use interface.

Comment: That's pretty much what you are doing when using an event. `MyTimer` publishes an event to which any class can register a handler. What the handler does is completely unknown to `MyTimer`. Have a look into https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/events/

Comment: @user1473213 That's exactly what this answer solves. `Timer` should not call methods on `Program`. It should invoke an `event` instead, and `Program` should register a listener for this event.

Answer (score 0):

I think Damien nailed it pretty much for this scenario.
Yet, I'd like to propose an alternative: Using a shared State Object.

You could define a `State` class, which does nothing else than hold the value of the tick-count.

You'd instanciate it in `Program` and pass it to the `MyTimer`. Mind that both classes now share the same instance (possibly introducing threading/concurrency issues if in multithreaded context).

`MyTimer` then would update the state on that shared Object.

Examples are Model/ViewModel classes in MVVM/WPF where you would bind some Control's property to that object's property.

Mind that `Program` wouldn't know of a occurring change out of the box. So that would have to be handled additionally. Either again via an Event, some "Observer Pattern" or similar.

As I said, events are the way to go *here* but I thought it couldn't hurt to suggest an alternative way of inter-class communication.